# Language selector and default language on filter bar

Tags: design-patterns, checkboxes, dropdown, drop-down-list

A user is able to choose supported languages from a language list on our platform. The user is required to set one default language (the system defaults to English). The language dropdown is available on the filter bar.

I'm concerned about this pattern - should these two actions be displayed in one dropdown, or would it be better to split them on the filter bar? If so, how might that be labeled? Languages + Default language to choose? In that case the user has to use 2 dropdowns, and it can increase error prevention...any ideas?[image: Dropdown with languages. Each language has a checkbox next to it in order to make the language supported, and a Make Default link next to it.]

Comment: Why not just display languages without additional options on the UI? And when a user selects a particular language you set it as a default language for that user. Because users won't simply change the language of the interface unless it's their preferred language.

Comment: it's not the interface language, but supported languages in the survey builder. So ie. some global company wants to have their survey in 20 languages for their offices around the world and set the English one as the default language (so when you open the survey it opens in english but you can switch the language in dropdown for one of other 19 languages)

Comment: I see, ok got it. Purely from a mental step perspective, I think you should let users to select supported languages first and "Make Default" should only appear on the selected languages. Otherwise, users might try to press on the "Make Default" link on a non-selected language and it would cause confusion.

Comment: makes sense - it's a good advice :) Thank you